# PHP :: (What does this mean/do?)

Tags: php

Kind of hard to Google "::" as it ignores the symbols!

So in a roustabout way, i'm trying to figure where :: fits into PHP.

Thanks

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double-colon is a static method call.

Here's the PHP manual page for static methods: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

And [this tutorial page also has useful information](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Static_Methods.html).

Answer (score 5):

This means static method.

```
Product::get_matching_products($keyword);
```

would mean that `get_matching_products` is static method on `Product`

Answer (score 2):

In simple way to say it, you can call a static method or variable from any part of your code without instantiating the class. And to achieve that you use ::

here is and example to help you from their manual

```
<?php
function Demonstration()
{
    return 'This is the result of demonstration()';
}

class MyStaticClass
{
    //public static $MyStaticVar = Demonstration(); //!!! FAILS: syntax error
    public static $MyStaticVar = null;

    public static function MyStaticInit()
    {
        //this is the static constructor
        //because in a function, everything is allowed, including initializing using other functions

        self::$MyStaticVar = Demonstration();
    }
} MyStaticClass::MyStaticInit(); //Call the static constructor

echo MyStaticClass::$MyStaticVar;
//This is the result of demonstration()
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**:: vs. ->, self vs. $this**

For people confused about the difference between **::** and **->** or **self** and **$this**, I present the following rules:

If the variable or method being referenced is declared as const or static, then you must use the **::** operator.

If the variable or method being referenced is not declared as const or static, then you must use the **->** operator.

If you are accessing a const or static variable or method from within a class, then you must use the self-reference **self**.

If you are accessing a variable or method from within a class that is not const or static, then you must use the self-referencing variable **$this**.